# How to use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog once in the prograde

Tags: java, jgrasp

How many times have you used the statement:
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog? If your answer is more than once go back and
revise your code so that you only use ONE JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Hint: consider using a variable of type String named output

Code

if(credit >= 120)

```
  {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You've graduated!");

  }//end if

  else if(credit >= 90)

  {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You're a senior.");

  }//end if

  else if(credit >= 60)

  {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You're a junior.");

  }//end if

  else if(credit >= 30)

  {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You're a sophomore.");

  }//end if

  else if(credit >=0)

  {

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You're a freshment.");

  }//end if


  else

  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"invalid input");
```

Comment: This question is confusingly worded. Is it copied from somewhere? As best I can tell, you are supposed to use a function to get the message string based on the `credit` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the if-else statements to generate the String to show, then use a single line to call `showMessageDialog()` using the String.

Answer (score 0):

//don't forget to import the JOptionPane library

//also I have no clue how you used your credit variable
public class prograde
{
    public void showJoption(String position)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, position);
    }

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //this is the class object that you can use to call the showJoption() method.
    prograde display = new prograde();

    if(credit >= 120)
    {
        display.showJoption("You've graduated!");
    }
    else if (credit >= 90)
    {
        display.showJoption("You're a senior.");
    }
    else if (credit >= 60)
    {
        display.showJoption("You're a junior.");
    }
    else if (credit >= 30)
    {
        display.showJoption("You're a sophomore.");
    }
    else if (credit >= 0)
    {
        display.showJoption("You're a freshment.");
    }
    else {
        display.showJoption("invalid input");
    }
}
```

}